# Laravel 8 LengthAwarePaginator for ajax returns data object as object not array

Tags: ajax, pagination, laravel-8

I have a collection object which I need to paginate. But as it is collection I have to paginate it manualy this way:

```
    $collection = $collection->sortByDesc('created');

    $paginatedCollection = new LengthAwarePaginator(
        $collection->forPage($page, $per_page),
        $collection->count(),
        $per_page,
        $page,
        ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()],
    );


    return $this->sendJsonResponse($paginatedCollection);
```

sendJsonResponse() looks like, but it have the same problem if I send it as is

```
public function sendJsonResponse(
    array|object $data = [], 
    string $message = '', 
    int $code = JsonResponse::HTTP_OK
): JsonResponse {
    return JsonResponseHandler::sendJsonResponse($data, $message, $code);
}
```

Then I need to get it in Ajax but the object with data which I get is not an array but object.

```
"data": {
    "12": {
        "id": 32,
        "customer_id": 3,
    },
    "11": {
        "id": 31,
        "customer_id": 3,
    },
}
```

As you can see PHP make a string keys from numeric array keys so the result in json is object. How can I get an array instead of object?